# How to enforce maps of the same order using spock framework

Tags: groovy, spock

The following test passes while I actually would like to see it fail. The order is important for my use case. However I thought groovy is always using linked lists so ordering should be testable.

```
def "test foo"() {
    given:
    def a = [a: 1, c: 3, b: 2]

    when:
    def b = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]

    then:
    a == b
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test order of keys in those two `LinkedHashMap` instances you can do the following:

```
def "test foo"() {
    given:
    def a = [a: 1, c: 3, b: 2]

    when:
    def b = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]

    then: "make sure maps are equal"
    a == b

    and: "make sure entries are defined in the same order"
    a.collect { it.key } == b.collect { it.key }
}
```

`LinkedHashMap` does not override `equals` method (it uses the one defined in `AbstractMap` class, the same one used by e.g. `HashMap`) and it only defines order of the iteration (order in which entries are added to the map).

Both assertions can be simplified to a single:

```
def "test foo"() {
    given:
    def a = [a: 1, c: 3, b: 2]

    when:
    def b = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]

    then: "compare ordered list of map entries"
    a.collect { it } == b.collect { it }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that only comparing the keys and ignoring the values?

Comment: Using the approach described here, `[a: 1, b: 2]` and `[a: 'uno', b: 'dos']` would be considered equal because the comparison is not accounting for values.

Comment: I see the answer has now beed edited to invalidate my question.  Please ignore.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, you're right. Testing keys order in this case could be done after we make sure that maps are equal. Otherwise we can get false sense of correctness as you mentioned in the 2nd comment. Updated the answer so it covers both assertions. Thanks!

Comment: @jeff Scott brown this  is as I understood it anyway. however I was hoping for some nicer way

Comment: "I was hoping for some nicer way" - I would do it with a custom comparator.  That would be more efficient and make more sense (to me).

Answer (score -1):

You could use toMapString() in your comparison

```
a.toMapString() == b.toMapString()
```

toMapString converts the map into a String which means the order will impact the comparison

`'[a:1, c:3, b:2]' == '[a:1, b:2, c:3]'`

will return false.

Comment: This is a bad idea because you could have keys and/or values that actually have different values but would return the same `String` representation.

Comment: I suppose that is possible if you don't have types on your Map.

Comment: "I suppose that is possible if you don't have types on your Map" - It is possible regardless of whether or not you use types on your `Map`.

Comment: Consider a `Person` class with `firstName`, `lastName` and `SSN` properties.  `equals` and `compareTo` account for all 3 properties, which is reasonable.  `toString()` could only account for `firstName` and `lastName` (just as an example), which is also totally reasonable.  Then if you have `Person` instances as values in your `Map`, 2 people with the same first and last name but different SSN will result in the same `String` representation.

Comment: Using types doesn't fix that problem.

Comment: Using `String` representations of instances in order to determine equality comes with a number of problems.

Comment: Fair point, and thanks for the example. I'd love to know if there is a single comparison that could be used rather than having to do two though. It feels like it should be possible in a single check.